# Deploy flask api on IIS server gives error 0x8007010b notification: ExecuteRequestHandler

Tags: python, flask, iis, fastcgi, flask-restful

I have to deploy flask app on IIS server. configured the handler settings and also configured the fastcgi module settings for IIS server as given in the following tutorial https://medium.com/@rajesh.r6r/deploying-a-python-flask-rest-api-on-iis-d8d9ebf886e9
and
https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8
I configured all the settings except url rewrite settings. I don't know how to configure it.
When I run the flask app through python IDLE it runs fine and app url is accessible through browser. But IIS gives the following errors

```
    Module     FastCgiModule
    Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
    Handler    pythonHandler
    Error Code     0x8007010b
```

I tried changing feature permissions but it gives error notifications like MapRequestHandler and ExecuteRequestHandler error codes:

```
    0x80070005, 0x80070002, 0x8007010b.
```

Something from the trace log is as follows:

```
   <failedRequest url="http://localhost:5000/"
           siteId="5"
           appPoolId="tes_flask"
           processId="20452"
           verb="GET"
           remoteUserName=""
           userName=""
           tokenUserName="NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"
           authenticationType="anonymous"
           activityId="{80000887-0001-F800-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
           failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
           statusCode="500"
           triggerStatusCode="500"
           timeTaken="0"
           xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
           >
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably a permission issue. Because 0x8007010b means The directory name is invalid.

1. Ensure that the identity of the application pool has administrator rights. You can create a user with administrator rights or directly set it as a local system.
2. Ensure that the application and FastCgiModule directories have read and write permissions.

Comment: setting up application pool identity to local system gives the following error :
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
An unknown FastCGI error occurred


                    Module    FastCgiModule
                    Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
                    Handler    Python FastCGI
                    Error Code    0x80070005

Comment: What about setting identity to custom account? Using administrator as custom account.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this issue I had to grant `Modify` and `Write` permissions to the `python.exe` for the `IUSR` user.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason i cannot comment under the posts. However the post of Andrea pointer me to the issue. I opened the python.exe path, in my case:
c:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310

i executed the following commands:
icacls . /grant "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR:(OI)(CI)(RX)"
icacls . /grant "Builtin\IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)(RX)"

After that i was able to open the Flask app through IIS.

Comment: You cannot comment because you do not yet have the [reputation](/help/privileges/comment) to comment on other people's posts. You could improve your answer by adding some more explanation -- did you execute it in the terminal? What does that command do? [Answer]

Answer (score 0):

for my case, I had to give full permissions IIS_IUSRS user on environment folder. I am using miniconda, so I had to go to miniconda3/envs folder and give that full permission with IIS_IUSRS to the xyz environment folder. I guess it worked in my case because, my python exe and wfastcgi.py files are all in this folder which my handler mappings check